# Annoying invalid syntax with pygame

Tags: python, syntax, pygame

I get a invalid syntax of this code and it seems so easy to figure out yet really hard for me.

```
#Svårighetsgrader
enditlevels = False
while (enditlevels == False):
    windowSurface.fill(WHITE)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if (event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1):
            mouse_coordinates = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if buttonEasy.collidepoint(mouse_coordinates):
                MOVE_SPEED = 9
                NEW_RABBIT = 40
                end_it_levels = True
        if (event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1):
            mouse_coordinates = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if buttonNormal.collidepoint(mouse_coordinates):
                MOVE_SPEED = 7
                NEW_RABBIT = 30
                end_it_levels = True
        if (event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1):
            mouse_coordinates = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if buttonHard.collidepoint(mouse_coordinates):
                MOVE_SPEED = 5
                NEW_RABBIT = 20
                end_it_levels = True
```

The error:

```
C:\Users\Rickard\My Programs\Python\slutarbete\Slutarbete>updatedSlutarbete.py
  File "C:\Users\Rickard\My Programs\Python\slutarbete\Slutarbete\updatedSlutarb
ete.py", line 182
    enditlevels = False
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

More code because I'm getting these errors all the time:

```
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#Börjar med att importera alla moduler för att få spelkoden att funka här.
#Importerar först alla tillgängliga moduler till pygame paketet.
#Sedan så sätter jag en begränsad uppsättning av konstanter och funktioner
#i global namespace av scriptet. Efter det importerar jag timern som är
#essentiell i spel osv.

import pygame, sys, random, math
from pygame.locals import *
from threading import Timer

#Börjar sätta upp spel funktionerna och klockan.

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()

_image_library = {}
def get_image(path):
        global _image_library
        image = _image_library.get(path)
        if image == None:
                canonicalized_path = path.replace('/', os.sep).replace('\\', os.sep)
                image = pygame.image.load(canonicalized_path)
                _image_library[path] = image
        return image

def movementVariables():
    global moveUp
    global moveDown
    global moveLeft
    global moveRight
    global levelOne
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    #Tangentbords variabler
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            #testkey
            if event.key == K_SPACE:
                levelOne = False
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                moveRight = False
                moveLeft = True
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                moveRight = True
                moveLeft = False
            if event.key == K_UP:
                moveDown = False
                moveUp = True
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                moveDown = True
                moveUp = False
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                moveLeft = False
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                moveRight = False
            if event.key == K_UP:
                moveUp = False
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                moveDown = False

def movementMechanism():
    if moveDown and player.bottom < WINDOW_HEIGHT:
        player.top += MOVE_SPEED
    if moveUp and player.top > 0:
        player.top -= MOVE_SPEED
    if moveLeft and player.left > 0:
        player.left -= MOVE_SPEED
    if moveRight and player.right < WINDOW_WIDTH:
        player.right += MOVE_SPEED
    windowSurface.blit(playerImage, player)



#Ger resolutionen till spelfönstret samt ger namnet för spelet och fönstret.

WINDOW_WIDTH = 640
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 400
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode ((WINDOW_WIDTH,
WINDOW_HEIGHT), 0)
icon = pygame.image.load('textures/systemicon.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
pygame.display.set_caption('Catch the rabbits!')

#Ger alla färger dess rgb koder, och vilken font och vinn texten.

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

textFont = pygame.font.SysFont("impact", 60)
textLevelOne = textFont.render("YOU THE FIRST LEVEL!", True, (193, 0, 0))
textLevelTwo = textFont.render("YOU THE SECOND LEVEL!", True, (193, 0, 0))
textLevelThree = textFont.render("YOU THE THIRD AND LAST LEVEL!/nCONGRATULATIONS!", True, (193, 0, 0))

#Spelarens och fiendernas data structurer.
#Fiendernas storlek.
#Laddar alla bitmap (.png) och ljud (.wav) filer till spelaren och fienderna
#samt bakgrundsbilderna 
rabbitCounter = 0
NEW_RABBIT = 40
RABBIT_SIZE = 64

pigCounter = 0
NEW_PIG = 40
PIG_SIZE = 64

boarCounter = 0
NEW_BOAR = 40
BOAR_SIZE = 64
#"Who Likes To Party" Kevin MacLeod (incompetech.com)
#"No Frills Salsa" Kevin MacLeod (incompetech.com) 
#Licensed under Creative Commons: By Attribution 3.0
#http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/
backgroundMusicMenu = pygame.mixer.Sound('music/Who Likes To Party.ogg')
pygame.mixer.music.load('music/No Frills Salsa.ogg')
foxSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('sounds/foxSound.wav')
rabbitSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('sounds/rabbitSound.wav')
pigSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('sounds/pigSound.wav')
boarSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('sounds/boarSound.wav')
background_image = pygame.image.load('textures/bg.jpg').convert()
player = pygame.Rect(420, 100, 40, 40)
buttonStart = pygame.Rect(220, 150, 200, 90)
buttonEasy = pygame.Rect(10, 150, 200, 90)
buttonNormal = pygame.Rect(220, 150, 200, 90)
buttonHard = pygame.Rect(430, 150, 200, 90)

rabbits = []
for i in range (20):
    rabbits.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOW_WIDTH
    - RABBIT_SIZE), random.randint (0, WINDOW_HEIGHT - RABBIT_SIZE),
    RABBIT_SIZE, RABBIT_SIZE))

pigs = []
for i in range (20):
    pigs.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOW_WIDTH
    - PIG_SIZE), random.randint (0, WINDOW_HEIGHT - PIG_SIZE),
    PIG_SIZE, PIG_SIZE))

boars = []
for i in range (20):
    boars.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOW_WIDTH
    - BOAR_SIZE), random.randint (0, WINDOW_HEIGHT - BOAR_SIZE),
    BOAR_SIZE, BOAR_SIZE))

#Rörlighetsvariablerna

moveLeft = False
moveRight = False
moveUp = False
moveDown = False

#Rörlighetshastigheten

MOVE_SPEED = 0

#Start Meny
menuMusic = False
endit is False
while endit is False:
    while menuMusic == False:
        backgroundMusicMenu.play()
        menuMusic = True
    windowSurface.fill(WHITE)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if (event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1):
            mouse_coordinates = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if buttonStart.collidepoint(mouse_coordinates):
                end_it = True
    windowSurface.blit(get_image('textures/buttonStart.png', buttonStart)



#Svårighetsgrader
enditlevel is False
while enditlevels is False:
    windowSurface.fill(WHITE)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if (event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1):
            mouse_coordinates = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if buttonEasy.collidepoint(mouse_coordinates):
                MOVE_SPEED = 9
                NEW_RABBIT = 40
                end_it_levels = True
        if (event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1):
            mouse_coordinates = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if buttonNormal.collidepoint(mouse_coordinates):
                MOVE_SPEED = 7
                NEW_RABBIT = 30
                end_it_levels = True
        if (event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1):
            mouse_coordinates = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if buttonHard.collidepoint(mouse_coordinates):
                MOVE_SPEED = 5
                NEW_RABBIT = 20
                end_it_levels = True
    windowSurface.blit(get_image('textures/buttonEasy.png'), buttonEasy)
    windowSurface.blit(get_image('textures/buttonNormal.png'), buttonNormal)
    windowSurface.blit(get_image('textures/buttonHard.png'), buttonHard)
    pygame.display.flip()

#Spel loopen
backgroundMusicMenu.stop()
levelOne = True
startSoundLevelOne = True
while levelOne == True:
    while startSoundLevelOne == True:
        rabbitSound.play()
        foxSound.play()
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        startSoundLevelOne = False    
#Checkar ifall quit
    movementVariables()

#Gör en loop som gör att det spawnar mera och mera kaniner
    rabbitCounter += 1
    if rabbitCounter >= NEW_RABBIT:
        rabbitCounter = 0
        rabbits.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOW_WIDTH
    - RABBIT_SIZE), random.randint (0, WINDOW_HEIGHT - RABBIT_SIZE),
    RABBIT_SIZE, RABBIT_SIZE))

#Snöbakgrunden sätts på bakgrunden när man väljt svårighetsgrad

    windowSurface.blit(get_image('textures/bg.jpg'),[0,0])

#Rörlighets mekanism så att spelaren inte går utanför skärmen samt inte går
#för fort.
    movementMechanism()

#Kaninernas texture blits
    for rabbit in rabbits:
        windowSurface.blit(get_image('rabbitImage.png'), rabbit)

#Random movement för kaninerna

    stepMovementNegativeRabbit = random.randrange(0, -3, -2)

    stepMovementPositiveRabbit = random.randrange(0, 3, 2)

    rabbitMovement = [((stepMovementNegativeRabbit),0), ((stepMovementPositiveRabbit), 0)
                      , (0, (stepMovementNegativeRabbit)), (0, (stepMovementPositiveRabbit))]
    for rabbit in rabbits:
        rabbit.move_ip(*random.choice(rabbitMovement))

#Checkning ifall spelaren rört en kanin
    for rabbit in rabbits[:]:

        if player.colliderect(rabbit):
            windowSurface.blit(get_image('textures/topic_rabbit2.png'), rabbit)
            windowSurface.blit(get_image('textures/Fox.png')), player)

        def explosionRabbit():
            for rabbit in rabbits:
                if player.colliderect(rabbit) and (moveLeft == False and
        moveRight == False and moveUp == False and
        moveDown == False):
                     rabbits.remove(rabbit)

        if player.colliderect(rabbit) and (moveLeft == False and
    moveRight == False and moveUp == False and moveDown == False):
            #timer inställningar
            tRabbit = Timer(0.1, explosionRabbit)
            tRabbit.start()

    if len(rabbits) == 0:
        rabbitCounter = 0
        windowSurface.blit (get_image(textLevelOne.png), (100, 104))
        levelOne = False
        windowSurface.fill((0,0,0))

    #Ritar fönstret
    pygame.display.update()
    mainClock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Please add part of the code before that line, it's possible that the error is hidden before the line 182.

Comment: With bool you don't need `while (enditlevels == False)` but `while enditlevels is False` which is for identity testing

Comment: @KobiK - `while not enditlevels:` :)

Comment: @iCodez you are right, just wanted to clear why not to use `==` with bool.

Comment: No syntax error for me. Are you sure that this code snippet creates the syntaxerror in your program on your computer?

Comment: @iCodez I put the whole code in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot a trailing `)` in this line:

```
windowSurface.blit(get_image('textures/buttonStart.png', buttonStart)
```

which is why you get a syntax error in the next line.

Aside: you now have a lot of lines like

```
endit is False
```

which doesn't do anything-- or rather, it checks to see whether `endit is False`, a bool, and then throws that result away.  This doesn't set `endit` to `False`.  If you want to use an `endit` variable here, you should use

```
endit = False
while not endit:
    [stuff here]
```